# Custom expandable card with child views

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am new to Android development and feel like this is a really trivial problem, but I cannot word it well enough to find a solution online, so I might as well ask the question here.

My goal is to create a reusable component that is essentially an expandable card like the one described here: https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#behavior.

To do it, I created a custom view that extends a CardView:

```
public class ExpandableCardView extends CardView {

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // get custom attributes
        TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ExpandableCardView, 0, 0);
        String heading = array.getString(R.styleable.ExpandableCardView_heading);
        array.recycle();

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_card_view, this, true);

        // set values
        TextView headingTextView = findViewById(R.id.card_heading);
        headingTextView.setText(heading.toUpperCase());

        // set collapse/expand click listener
        ImageView collapseExpandButton = findViewById(R.id.collapse_expand_card_button);
        collapseExpandButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> toggleCardBodyVisibility());
    }

    private void toggleCardBodyVisibility() {
        LinearLayout description = findViewById(R.id.card_body);
        ImageView imageButton = findViewById(R.id.collapse_expand_card_button);

        if (description.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up);
        } else {
            description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_down);
        }
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/expandable_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_header"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="HEADING"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapse_expand_card_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_body"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Ultimately I want to be able to use it like so in my activities, usually multiple instances per activity:

```
<xx.xyz.yy.customviews.ExpandableCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_xyz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    custom_xxx:heading="SOME HEADING" >

    <SomeView></SomeView>

</xx.xyz.yy.customviews.ExpandableCardView>
```

Where *SomeView* is any text, image, layout or another custom view altogether, typically with data bound from the activity.

How do I get it to render *SomeView* inside the card body? I want to take whatever child structure is defined within the custom view and show it in the card body when it is expanded. Hope I made it easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a better approach would be to define the layout that will be inserted into the `CardView` ("SomeView") in a separate file and reference it with a custom attribute like this:

```
<xx.xyz.yy.customviews.ExpandableCardView
    android:id="@+id/card_xyz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    custom_xxx:heading="SOME HEADING" 
    custom_xxx:expandedView="@layout/some_view"/>
```

I'll explain my rationale at the end, but let's look at an answer to your question as stated.

What you are probably seeing with your code is `SomeView` and `expandable_card_view` appearing all at once in the layout. This is because `SomeView` is implicitly inflated with the `CardView` and then `expandable_card_view` is added through an explicit inflation. Since working with layout XML files directly is difficult, we will let the implicit inflation occur such that the custom `CardView` just contains `SomeView`.

We will then remove `SomeView` from the layout, stash it, and insert `expandable_card_view` in its place. Once this is done, `SomeView` will be reinserted into the `LinearLayout` with the id `card_body`. All this has to be done after the completion of the initial layout. To get control after the initial layout is complete, we will use [`ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener). Here is the updated code. (I have removed a few things to simplify the example.)

[image: [video]]

**ExpandableCardView**

```
public class ExpandableCardView extends CardView {

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Get control after layout is complete.
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Remove listener so it won't be called again
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                // Get the view we want to insert into the LinearLayut called "card_body" and
                // remove it from the custom CardView.
                View childView = getChildAt(0);
                removeAllViews();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_card_view, ExpandableCardView.this, true);

                // Insert the view into the LinearLayout.
                ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.card_body)).addView(childView);

                // And the rest of the stuff...
                TextView headingTextView = findViewById(R.id.card_heading);
                headingTextView.setText("THE HEADING");

                // set collapse/expand click listener
                ImageView collapseExpandButton = findViewById(R.id.collapse_expand_card_button);
                collapseExpandButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> toggleCardBodyVisibility());
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggleCardBodyVisibility() {
        LinearLayout description = findViewById(R.id.card_body);
        ImageView imageButton = findViewById(R.id.collapse_expand_card_button);

        if (description.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_up);
        } else {
            description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_down);
        }
    }
}
```

**expandable_card_view.java**
The `CardView` tag is changed to `merge` to avoid a `CardView` directly nested within a `CardView`.

```
<merge
    android:id="@+id/expandable_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/card_header"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/card_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="HEADING"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapse_expand_card_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_body"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.customcardview.ExpandableCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/childView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Say my name."
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.example.customcardview.ExpandableCardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, why do I suggest that you use a custom attribute to include `SomeView` in the layout as I identified at the beginning? In the way outlined above, `SomeView` will always be inflated and there is some effort to switch the layout around although `SomeView` may never be shown. This would be expensive if you have a lot of custom `CardViews` in a `RecyclerView` for instance. By using a custom attribute to reference an external layout, you would only need to inflate `SomeView` when it is being shown and the code would be a lot simpler and easier to understand. Just my two cents and it may not really matter depending upon how you intend to use the custom view.

Comment: Much appreciate you answering. Just tried it, works as expected! Not long after asking this I created a public method on the ExpandableCardView to add a child view to the card body. Then I just declared a layout in a separate file, inflated it in the activity and called that method. The reason I think it is not ideal is because I have many different cards with simple content I don`t want to declare separate layout files for.
Also my collapse animation is kind of odd - the card body quickly collapses and the content fades out shortly after that. Anything I can do about that?

Comment: @DoubleZ Hard to say from the description. If this continues to be a problem, it would be best to post another question highlighting the issue you are having.

Comment: Replacing custom view root element androidx.cardview.widget.CardView with the merge tag helped with the animation, even though I am not sure why exactly.